# MailBox UnAvailable 5.7.1. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, smtp, sendmail

Below code is working fine if I send mails which are in xyz.rw domain (like abcd@xyz.rw, test@xyz.rw). When I tried to send mail to my gmail account, below error occurred. Its not working for other domain mail ids

> MailBox Unavailable 5.7.1. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to
>   relay

Please let me know how to fix this.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.Host = "10.8.12.242";
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword);
smtp.Timeout = 30000;

MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderID, "abcd@xyz.rw", "Information Entreprise", "Hello, that message has been sent as consiquence of mail sending test.");
try
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

550 5.7.1 Unable to Relay’ code error generally occurs when the user tries to send emails outside his domain.

**Causes for the error:**

1. The outgoing mail server could not identify the sender.
2. There are some issues while authenticating the sender on the server
   and thus restricting them to send emails.
3. The receiver domain’s recipient policy has imposed restrictions on
   the sender’s domain / department. The Exchange Database is corrupt.
4. A properly configured mail server is extremely restrictive with
   relaying, to prevent it from being abused by spammers to send mails.

So, That's a config issue in the mail servier. It doesn't allow you (your IP, your sender address) to send mail to the recipient.

Solution : you need to add the address to IIS Manager. Goto *IIS Manager* -> `Default SMTP Server` -> `Properties` -> `Access` -> `Relay` -> `allow only from the list below` -> `add` -> 'Address Here' -> Click `OK`

Comment: I connected to "10.8.12.242" machine and opened IIS Manager. but didn't find "Default SMTP Server". Can you let me know where exactly I can find Default SMTP server

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the solution is set the 
access - connection control - connection : "all except the list below"
access - relay restriction - relay : "all except the list below"
security - add domain users

and remember to set the firewall setting to allow port 25 outbound